# AWK to search for a for a string and print full text where string occurs

Tags: awk

I have a document containing several lines of text.

**Example(not actual):**

> *Prepare 42 Locked  delete from table where type='test' and user_id='099'and number='+66719919*

I want to be able to search for user_id where ever it occurs in the document (which does not follow a pattern) and have the output as:

> user_id=009

OR

> 009

Please how do I achieve this using awk?

Thanks.

Comment: Can `user_id=NUM` occur across two lines?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/user_id/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/user_id/){split($i,a,"=");print a[2]}}}' your_file
```

tested:

```
> echo "*Prepare type='test' and user_id='099' and number='+66719919*" | awk '/user_id/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/user_id/){split($i,a,"=");print a[2]}}}'
'099'
```

another one:

```
> echo "*Prepare type='test' and user_id='099' and number='+66719919*" | awk '/user_id/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/user_id/){ print $i}}}'
user_id='099'
```

Comment: Nice one Sarathi. Worked as well. Could you please explain to an awk novice if possible, what the second command? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use grep:

```
grep -o "user_id='\?[0-9]*'\?"
```

Append `tr` to remove the quotes:

```
grep -o "user_id='\?[0-9]*'\?" | tr -d \'
```

Comment: Thanks Thor. Worked perfectly as expected. Kudos. Cheers.

Comment: @ace: glad it worked for you. The way to say thanks around here is by upvoting useful answer and [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/186615) the best answer.